# Simple way to calculate the sum of all lengths of strings in a list

Tags: python, list, sum

I have lists that contain multiple strings like:

`['beth', 'Nissan', 'apple', 'three']`

I am searching for a short and easy way (inline if possible) to get the sum of all individual strings in this list. This is the code I currently have:

```
sum = 0
for string in list_of_strings:
    sum += len(string)
```

Comment: Please clarify whether you want the sum or a cummulative sum.

Comment: Apart from shadowing the builtin function [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum), the code you already have is quite fine.

Comment: @GáborPálovics Thanks for the tip, i fixed the title. I meant the sum of all lengths.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this

```
>>> strlist = ['beth', 'Nissan', 'apple', 'three']
>>> sum(len(x) for x in strlist)
20
```

Comment: This solution is great, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you want the sum use:

```py
result = sum([len(s) for s in list_of_strings])
```

If you are interested in the cummulative sum use:

```py
import numpy as np

result = np.cumsum([len(s) for s in list_of_strings])
```

Comment: The second solution returns an array of all the partial cumulative sums, but the first solution works great.

Comment: I left a comment since it's unclear based on your question what you need. The question mentions cummulative sum while the description is about normal sum.

Comment: The `list` creation in the `sum` function is unnecessary and less efficient.  Can/should be removed for a generator statement.

Comment: @S3DEV Actually it's likely to be the opposite unless the list is very long.  Generator overhead is large in Python.

Comment: @wim - Ok, will have a bit more research into that.  Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

You can use join to first concatenate the strings then calculate the length at once:

```
list_of_strings = ['beth', 'Nissan', 'apple', 'three']
len(''.join(list_of_strings))
```

Comment: Why waste the memory to create an extra string which will be immediately garbage collected anyway?

Comment: @wim - Trivial in this case, but nonetheless thanks for the comment.  Was interested in why this was downvoted.

Comment: @wim Could be another space–time tradeoff where a unique call to the function is faster than calling it n times (where n is your number of strings you concatenate).

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can try this:

```
list_of_strings = ['beth', 'Nissan', 'apple', 'three']

s = sum(map(len, list_of_strings))
```